# How to link data from nested relational tables in a C# query

Tags: c#, linq, non-relational-database

I have a mock design-time IList static data structure mirroring what will be stored in a production database. The model has a one-to-many relationship (a Reading contains many Measurements) but also a linked many-to-one (a Measurement is of a MeasurementType). I need to return an IEnumerable of Reading with each entry containing a list of it's Measurements but also each Measurement needs the MeasurementType object to contain the relevant object form the MeasurementTypes list.

The Measurements and Type properties in the model classes will not be persisted in the database.

I can see how to return the list of Readings to my application with the Measurements list property populated with matching objects from the measurements list but am struggling on the best way to populate the Type property in each measurement for the reading with the relevant object from the measurementTypes list based on the id property so I can also filter out Measurement objects whose measementType is not set to visible.

The query below fails as the Type property is null, how do I join in the Type object from the measurementTypes list by Id so it can be used in the query?? Or is there a better way to do this rather than a query in a foreach loop?

```
foreach (var reading in readings)
{
    reading.Measurements = measurements.Where(m => (m.ReadingId == reading.Id) && (m.Type.Visible)).ToList();
}

return readings;
```

(classes are simplified for clarity)

```
public class Reading
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Measurement>? Measurements { get; set; }
}

public class Measurement
{
    public int MeasurementTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ReadingId { get; set; }
    public MeasurementType? Type { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}  

public class MeasurementType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}

measurementTypes = new List<MeasurementType>()
{
    new MeasurementType { Id = 1, Name = "A name", Visible = true }
    ...
};

measurements = new List<Measurement>()
{
    new Measurement { ReadingId = 1, MeasurementTypeId = 1, Value = 100 }
    ...
};

readings = new List<Reading>()
{
    new Reading { Id = 1, DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-366) }
...
};
```

Comment: (m.ReadingId == reading.Id) && (m.Type != null) && (m.Type.Visible)

Answer (score 0):

The relation between Measurement and MeasurementType has to be build manually.
You need to assign to **Type** field from one of the relevant values from list of MeasurementType.
One approach you can try is as below:

Introduce a constructor in Measurement

```
    public class Measurement
    {
        // for mock tests
        public Measurement(int measurementTypeId, int readingId, int value, IEnumerable<MeasurementType> measurementTypes)
        {
            MeasurementTypeId = measurementTypeId;
            ReadingId = readingId;
            Type = measurementTypes.Single(mt=>mt.Id==measurementTypeId),
            Value = value;
        }

        public int MeasurementTypeId { get; set; }
        public int ReadingId { get; set; }
        public MeasurementType Type { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

then while building list of Measurement:

```
measurementTypes = new List<MeasurementType>()
{
    new MeasurementType { Id = 1, Name = "A name", Visible = true }
...
};

measurements = new List<Measurement>()
{
    new Measurement (1,  1,  100, measurementTypes) 
 ....
};
```